# Apparently duplicate but time sensitive questions?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

When it comes to frameworks, they tend to evolve over time.   Sometimes there are questions that are over a year old and you effectively want to ask the same question again to see what the state of play is.

Should you just say in your question, this duplicates X, but I'm wanting an update?

or?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-to-get-attention-for-your-old-unanswered-questions

Comment: @Ether, Are you sure that is a relevant duplicate? Or would time have obsoleted that question? :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presumably if you want to ask the same question at a later time, none of the existing answers satisfy your current problem.

In that case, it's okay to ask a new question. Be sure to reference the old question, stating why none of the solutions work for your situation, or why those answers are out of date.

If you just have a general question about how something works, for example, asking a new question is fine, *as long as you're sure there is a significant change in the expected answer* (even if you're not sure what the new answer will be). So in the case of an update to a framework, this could be the case if you see some feature was revamped in their changelog. (When in doubt, provide evidence of a significant change in the new question.)

What we want to avoid is adding new/duplicate questions to the system where the same answer knowledge is decentralized into more than one question. That's the idea behind closing a question as a duplicate of another question.